# Where does the equation of asymptotes of a hyperbola come from?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It's known that the asymptotes of a hyperbola $\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}-\frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}}=1$ is given by $y=\pm\frac{b}{a}x$ if $a>b$.

I  tried to find a proof of the fact that why the equations of these asymptotes are like that,however the only reference (Thomas calculus  book) that I found explained 
that the two asymptotes are derived by letting $\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}-\frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}}=0$.

---

It would be highly appreciated if someone prove why the equation of the asymptotes have such form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asymptotes of hyperbola](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2603632/asymptotes-of-hyperbola)

Comment: Recently asked similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3666824/how-we-calculate-the-asymptotes-of-a-general-hyperbola/3666906#3666906

Comment: Related:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3329775/571692

Comment: If your attitude is to blame your books, I fear for your mathematical future.

Comment: I think we can improve this question by removing the third paragraph. I'm not sure if it serves any purpose other than as a rant, which is inappropriate for SE.

Comment: @TonyK,this is not indeed the book I've chosen,I know some better books,but just because of the university I have to read them.Since I'm a student it looks that I have to read them and argue that the books are all complete ,however if I were a professor and I said the same words,no one would blame me,the truth is stable and remains the same,no matter who says that.

Comment: @ Bladewood, If saying the truth is considered as inappropriate , I will stop contributing to SE,Of course some attitudes are defined,but "It is not people who break ethical standards who are regarded as aliens. It is people like me who are isolated."


Grigori Perelman.

Comment: number, you are no Grigori Perelman.

Comment: @  TonyK,Of course I'm not,I even cannot be his student.

Comment: Anyway I will edit the question and I leave it to the users to post "appropriately."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the focus-directrix definition of the hyperbola:

> Given a (focus) point $F=(c,0)$ and a (directrix) line $\delta: x=d$, say, with $0<d<c$, the hyperbola is the locus of points $P$ such that $$\text{distance from $F$}=\text{eccentricity}\cdot(\text{distance from $\delta$})$$ for some $\text{eccentricity}$ $e > 1$.

For $P$ *really-really-really-really-$\cdots$-really* far away from the origin, its distance to $F$ is *virtually-indistinguishable* from its distance to the origin; and its distance from $\delta$ is *virtually-indistinguishable* from its distance to the $y$-axis. This makes $P$ *virtually-indistinguishable* from a point $Q$ travelling on a locus defined by
$$\text{distance from $O$} =  \text{eccentricity}\cdot(\text{distance from $y$-axis})$$
The equation for $Q$'s locus is $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=e x=\frac{c}{a}x=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{a}x \quad\to\quad
x^2+y^2=\frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2}x^2\quad\to\quad \frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=0$$
(with $a:=c/e$ and $b:=\sqrt{c^2-a^2}$, which (one can show) match our common interpretations of these values), and we recognize this as representing a pair of crossed lines. We see, then, that on a grand scale, the hyperbola approaches these lines, which we accordingly call its *asymptotes*. $\square$

Answer (score 12):

**Edited to do it properly** -- see below

*Original post:*

We have
$$y=b\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a^2}-1}=\frac{b}{a}x\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{x^2}}$$
And as $x\to\pm\infty$, $\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{x^2}}\to 1$.

*End of original post*

But as mentioned in the comments, it is not enough to show that $\frac{y}{bx/a}\to 1$. We have to show that $y-\frac{b}{a} x\to 0$:

$$y-\frac{b}{a}x=\frac{b}{a}x\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{x^2}}-1\right)$$
But
$$1-\frac{a^2}{x^2}\le\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{x^2}}<1$$
So
$$\left|\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{x^2}}-1\right|\le\frac{a^2}{x^2}$$
Therefore
$$\left|y-\frac{b}{a}x\right|\le\frac{b}{a}|x|\cdot\frac{a^2}{x^2}=\frac{ba}{|x|}$$
which tends to $0$ as $x\to\pm\infty$.

Comment: Thanks fo the answer,you say $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{x^2}}=1$,But why we can't say $$\lim_{x \to +\infty}y=\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{b}{a}x\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{x^2}}=\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{b}{a}x\lim_{x \to +\infty}\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{x^2}}=+\infty$$?

Comment: @number: Since $y$ *does* get infinitely-large along with $x$, the infinite limiting statement is true. The question is, though: *How does $y$ **compare** to $x$ in the long run?* So, perhaps a better way to capture this is $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{y}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{x^2}} = \frac{b}{a}\cdot \lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{x^2}}=\frac{b}{a}\cdot 1$$

Comment: How did you recolour the MSE logo for your profile pic?

Comment: Actually, @Blue, we are both wrong: it is not enough that $\dfrac{y}{(b/a)x}$ tends to $1$; for an asymptote, we need that $y - (b/a)x$ tends to $0$.

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish: Microsoft Paint 3D, IIRC.

Comment: @TonyK Why is that? Do you have an example?

Comment: @TonyK Haha, my apologies. My second question was if you have an example where $y/f(x)\apr1$ but $y=f(x)$ does **not** have an asymptote (since you say the quotient approaching unity does not guarantee an asymptote).

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish: you confused me there. I though you were responding to my response to your comment, but no. Anyway: For a function to have an asymptote, it must approach that asymptote arbitrarily closely _in absolute terms_, not just in relative terms. So although my post shows that $\frac{b}{a}x$ is the only asymptote possible, it doesn't show that $\frac{b}{a}x$ is necessarily an asymptote -- it might be that there is no asymptote. For instance, $f(x)=x+\sin x$.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Yes, you are quite right! I think my answer is correct now $-$ see my edit.

Answer (score 6):

The other answers have tried to give more rigorous arguments, which I would like to complement with a heuristic way which doesn't need further manipulation of the equation:

From looking at the hyperbola, it is obvious that the asymptotes are lines that the curve approaches when $x$ and $y$ become very large, in particular larger than $a$ or $b$ (BTW, the condition $a<b$ seems unnecessary to me). Then, in the defining equation$$\frac{x²}{a²}-\frac{y²}{b²}=1\,,$$ you have two large numbers on the left-hand side whose difference is $1$. In other words, their difference is much smaller than the numbers themselves, and it becomes a good approximation to just neglect the $1$ on the right-hand side. Furthermore, the approximation becomes better which increasing $x$ and $y$. Thus, $$\frac{x²}{a²}-\frac{y²}{b²}=0\,,$$ is at least a good candidate for the equation of the asymptotes.

Comment: This is a great heuristic, the type of which I’ve seen many times in physics. We intelligently (usually with foresight) replace some expressions with simpler ones, so the equations can be analytically solved.

Answer (score 2):

Aymptotes of a hyperbola are a limiting case of tangents which tend to meet the hyperbola at $\infty$.So take a general equation of line $y=mx+c$ and plug it into the hyperbola equation.This gives you
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{(mx+c)^2}{b^2}=1$$ which gives $$x^2(\frac{1}{a^2}-\frac{m^2}{b^2})-\frac{2mcx}{b}-\frac{c^2}{b^2}-1=0$$ and we know that this eqaution should have both roots tending to infinity(since i said aymptotes of a hyperbola are just tangents which meet the hyperbola at $\infty$).Now applying conditions for roots tending to $\infty$ for a quadratic equations gives coeffecient of $x^2=0,x=0$ and $constant\neq 0$(this can be proved by assuming $\alpha$, $\beta$ as roots of equation $px^2+qx+r$ and both should tend to zero,which means $\frac{1}{\alpha},\frac{1}{\beta}$ should tend to zero,now forming a quadratic equation with $\frac{1}{\alpha},\frac{1}{\beta}$ gives us $rx^2+qx+p=0$ which has both roots tending to zero if $p\to 0,q\to 0$ and $r\neq o$) and thus we get $$\frac{1}{a^2}-\frac{m^2}{b^2}=0\space and\space \frac{2mc}{b}=0$$ which gives us $$m=\pm\frac{b}{a} and\space c=0$$ and which on substituting in $y=mx+c$ and multiplying both equations  gives the famous pair of asymptotes formula as you said $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=0$$ Just as a side note; this method can be applied to find the asymptotes of any curve (even twisted, translated and rotated hyperbolae for that matter). Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks you for the answer,can you explain why do we need to plug $y=mx+c$ into the equation of the hyperbola?

Comment: We are taking trying to find a pair of lines which touch the graph as we move further away from its centre, (AKA asymptotes). As these lines are no different from any of the other lines in the plane in terms of algebra, ie every line can be written as y = mx +c, we can assume the line to be y = mx +c and for particular values for m and c, this line will be our asymptote. We find those particular values by applying conditions for the roots.It's just like finding intersection points of two equations by substituting one in other(in algebraic perspective)

Answer (score 1):

Consider a family of hyperbolas

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=t,$$ for any real number $t\ne 0.$ When $t=0,$ this just gives a pair of intersecting straight lines.

By a linear transformation (which does not change the character of the conic), you can consider the affine family of hyperbolas $$xy=t$$ instead. Then considering $y$ as a function of $x$ gives $$y=\frac tx,$$ where we may take $t>0$ without loss of generality.

We know that as $x\to\pm \infty,$ then $y\to 0.$ (By a similar reasoning, $x=0$ when $y=\pm\infty.$)

Therefore, it follows that the equation $y=0$ is asymptotic to $y=t/x,$ and that $x=0$ is asymptotic to $x=t/y.$

> In general, each member of the family is asymptotic to the pair of lines obtained when $t=0.$ (The so-called degenerate case.)

Hence, our original family $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=t,$$ when we invert the transformation, must also be asymptotic to the lines obtained when we set $t=0.$ This gives the result.